# how to assign input field file array to saparate input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form where I have a file input field, where I can choose multiple files. Now the problem is that
If I choose 3 files then it should create 3 input fields having files from 1 to 3. Eg can be seen below.

[image]

**I want to to do it using jquery. The code which i have written is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" class="form-group" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="track" name="tracks" multiple>
    <button type="button" id="btn-submit"> Upload</button>

    <script>
        $(document).on("click", "#btn-submit", function() {
            
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What approach or methodologies should I use to get the result expected?

**Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: You haven't written any code for this specific problem, so you can't pretend anyone to do the job for you. You can reformulate your question to ask something like "What method could I use to solve this problem?" The I would ask you: "You should use DOM, through which you can create HTML objects", but I doubt you can do this, because preselecting files in an input field is a security issue. So a better approach would be to limit the upload to one file and create a new input when a file has been choosen in the existing one, giving the user the chance to choose a new file.

Comment: You are right carles, I want to create html objects but I have only worked with text field and no idea about files. Please suggest how can I come out of it.

Comment: First of all I would set the event "onchange", not on "click" and then I would use createElement to create more input fields (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp). Since you will also need to attach an event to the new element using myelement.onchange = thefunction, then I would write a separate function for this action, instead of declaring an inline function. Then I would keep a count of the total amount of input fields and how many input fields have been actually set, to avoid creating new ones.